# how Upload Max Size using ajax?

Tags: ajax

how upload file The size of the top 10MB using ajax
Are there settings in ajax

like:
autoUpload: true,
singleFileUploads: false,

for the example:
maxfilesize: 20mb or isUploadfile: true

tanks

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do on the client (JS, frameworks, whatever) you'll really have to check the `Content-length` in the HTTP header on the server when the upload starts.

It is very easy to work around any client-side limitation you may put in place.

Depending on your server technology this may be very easy or difficult to do and varies greatly from, say, PHP to ASP.NET or Rails.